# How is the behaviour of an atom particles as the atom approaches the speed of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, atomic-physics, relativity

There are many questions regarding what it means to accelerate the constituents of an  atom towards to the speed of light, but I am not able to find any cogent article as to what the dynamics of the atom as a whole is.

For example, we know from relativity how a mass or body (made up of atoms) behaves as we approach light speed but that is not the question being asked.  The question is how is the individual atom's behavioural model (e.g. wave equation) changed when accelerated towards the speed of light.

Comment: Are you asking how time dilation & length contraction affect the wavefunction of an atom?

Comment: I'm wondering what happens if the energetic atom absorbs a low energy photon?

Comment: @user6760 A low energy photon still has energy so the energetic atom becomes more energetic.

Comment: This question is far too broad, a decent answer would be a textbook on relativistic quantum mechanics. You could start here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics

Comment: Not sure relativistic quantum approach is necessary here. I think that *within* the atom nothing change. Which is also why I find relativistic mass just confusing but this is another story. As I've said nothing should change as far the inner structure of the *individual* atom and its energy levels are considered. Hope not to be wrong. Concerning us as observer we see is inertia rising according to SR.

Comment: @PM 2RIng, yes that is really the point of the question.   If mass increases and there is length contraction, then there must be a commensurate set of transformations within the atom to allow these relativistic observations to be made at the macro level.

Comment: As John's linked answer says, in the rest frame of the atom, the atom itself is unchanged. To an observer moving at close to $c$ relative to the atom, the shapes of the atom's electron orbitals are flattened by the length contraction, and the lifetimes of its excited states are dilated. Modern relativity doesn't use relativistic mass because it's too confusing and can lead to incorrect conclusions.